# What's this integral definition?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I've seen the integral definition:

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = F(b)-F(a) = \lim_{x\rightarrow b-}F(b) - \lim_{x\rightarrow a_+}F(a)$$

Anyone know what's this "limit version" called?

I know it applies to indefinite integrals.

Comment: This is because $F(x)$ is continuous on $[a.b]$

Comment: So it is just a manipulation, AFAIK.

Comment: Both sided limits=RHL=LHL-> In a continuous function.

Comment: Consider the example $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{dx\over 1+x^2}=\arctan x\biggr|_{-\infty}^\infty:=\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x-\lim_{x\to-\infty}\arctan x\ .$$